# How to find the question or answer relating to this revision?

Tags: support

I used Google to search for *wmctrl -a and window id*.

The first hit was a link to a revision at Ask Ubuntu:

[image: Google search]

And clicking it gave me this link in the address bar:

`https://askubuntu.com/revisions/865e9305-bef6-4397-9097-2848d0dc1233/view-source` with the following contents:

[image: Contents of the revision page]

But I can't figure out where that revision originated. How do I find the corresponding question or answer?

Comment: Just a pointer, unless I'm mistaken if you have `-a` in your search term, it would show only the results *without* the string "a" (`-string` in search term means show results without "`string`"). If you meant to search for results *with* "`wmctrl -a`", then you need to search with `wmctrl "-a"` or `"wmctrl -a"`.

Comment: I will remember that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would normally get there by [Googling stand-out phrases in quotation marks](https://www.google.com/search?q="if+you+have+wmctrl+installed"), but that's messy and relies on those phrases still being there when Google reads it. At least it's fast, but in this case, not accurate enough.

Found a "better" way. Slower but cleaner. You can look up posts by revision GUID on [Data.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/new) using the following query:

```
SELECT PostId as [Post Link] FROM PostHistory WHERE RevisionGUID = '...';
```

That returns https://askubuntu.com/q/616767

It's gnarly-as-hell but it will work most of the time. Note that Data.SE tends to lag behind the production databases. It gets regular dumps. Not an issue here but it could be for a brand new revision.

Comment: Thanks! Your query to data.SE came up with the correct question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/616738/how-do-i-close-a-new-firefox-window-from-the-terminal Once I figured out what to do, the search took 1ms.

Comment: Sorry, I was rushing so much I didn't even notice the result from Google wasn't the same as the one from Data.SE (which is why I didn't include the result). Absolute Hodor. Sorry for making you run the query yourself.

Comment: Not at all! I never knew anything about Data.SE and now I do.